# groupByKey in Haskell - How to group items in a list by a function?

Tags: haskell

Given a list `[v]` and a keying function `f :: v -> k`, I want to generate a map `Map k [v]`. Does something like this exist in Haskell?

```
import Data.Map

groupByKey :: (v -> k) -> [v] -> Map k [v]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `fromListWith`, like so:

```
import Data.Map
groupByKey :: (Ord k) => (v -> k) -> [v] -> Map k [v]
groupByKey getkey
  = fromListWith (++) . fmap (\val -> (getkey val, [val]))
```

so that:

```
> groupByKey length $ words "hello there my good friend"
fromList [(2,["my"]),(4,["good"]),(5,["there","hello"]),(6,["friend"])]
>
```

Comment: I don't like `fromListWith` because it's too hard to remember which way the combining function is applied. I'd much rather see something like `(a -> b) -> (a -> b -> b) -> [(k, a)] -> Map k b`, but even that needs to specify the order in which list elements are added to the `Map`. Hrmph. Maybe you'll have a good idea, in which case I can add it to `Data.Map`.

Comment: @dfeuer, I actually *do* have an idea.  Consider: `fromFold :: (Ord k, Monoid m, Foldable t) => t (k, m) -> Map k m` . By implicitly using the associative monoid op, it doesn't matter which argument is the value being "inserted" -- ultimately, each key is mapped to the `mconcat` of the list of values for the key (with values ordered the same as the input list).  Add `fromFoldr :: (Ord k, Foldable t) => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t (k, a) -> Map k b` (and `fromFoldl`) to avoid explicit monoid instances, and it starts looking pretty good.  Maybe I should propose something to libraries@haskell.org?

Comment: Consider the performance impact of `a++(b++c)` vs `(a++b)++c`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow -- isn't this the same as the need to consider the performance impact of `foldMap` versus `foldr` versus `foldl` versus various strict variants?  Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Right. You need to be aware how the fold associates the operations. And you'll often want multiple options.

Comment: Shall I accept this answer or is there a cleaner/better alternative?

Comment: @pathikrit, sorry for hijacking your question with these comments.  I think @dfeuer and I are both lamenting the fact that `fromListWith` is a little awkward and unintuitive, but right now it seems to be the best approach with current `Data.Map` API.